# ListView not refreshing in a custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have a custom view group which allowed my screen to swip to the right when I call the menu button letting appear a second layout (my menu).

I have similars activities in my project without the menu and it works fine.
it's a simple view with a listview in it which displays data from webservices.

when I come on this activity, the content of my listView is not refreshed when data arrives. but when i press the menu button, the view swip and the content of my list view appears (without images, that appears when i scroll my listView).

*here is the event rased when the menu button is pressed :*

```
public void customScroll(final int i) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i == 0) {
                    for (int inc = 200; inc >= 0; inc -= 5) {
                        final int inc2 = inc;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               //cvg is the implementation of my customViewGroup
                                cvg.scrollTo(inc2);
                            }
                        });
                        try {

                            synchronized (this) {
                                wait(5);
                            }

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int inc = 0; inc <= 200; inc += 5) {
                        final int inc2 = inc;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                cvg.scrollTo(inc2);
                            }
                        });
                        try {

                            synchronized (this) {
                                wait(5);
                            }

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

*And that is the thread wich is run in "runOnUiThread" when my data are downloaded :*

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (doubleVideos != null && doubleVideos.size() > 0) {
                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for (int i = 0; i < doubleVideos.size(); i++) {
                    videoAdapter.add(doubleVideos.get(i));
                }
            }
            videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the behavior of my activity is quite strange, ask me if you don't understand.
i've tried already tried :

```
cvg.invalidate();
            cvg.scrollTo(20);
            //listView.notify();
            listView.refreshDrawableState();
            cvg.refreshDrawableState();
            listView.bringToFront();
            listView.invalidate();
            cvg.invalidate();
            listView.refreshDrawableState();
```

billion thanks for those who red this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before.., I think you didn't implement **ViewGroup** in the proper way! In the custom ViewGroup call the `measure` method for each child before calling the `layout` method on the `onLayout`.